# What is the regex for this the pattern "--> xxx"

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

"--> xxx", where xxx is a digit

example:

```
--> 200
--> 201
--> 403
```

I want to check if a string begins with that pattern

My attempt:

```
message.contains(Regex("-->\\s+(\\d+)"))
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] - right now there are a lot of open questions in your code snippet. For example: What's `message`? A string? `String.contains` does not accept regular expressions as its argument. And what's `Regex`? A method? How is it defined and what does it return? And in either case, what does your code do when you try to run it and how is that different from what you want it to do?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt()

Comment: sorry. it's actually kotlin in android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java `String` you'd use the regex you have plus ".*" to match other characters after digits with `matches(regex)`:

```
message.matches("-->\\s+(\\d+).*")
```

So these are all true:

```
"--> 200 xyz".matches("-->\\s+(\\d+).*")
"--> 403".matches("-->\\s+(\\d+).*")
```

If repeating this often you may be better off creating a `Pattern` and `Matcher` once before resetting the matcher instance each time for a string to check:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-->\\s+(\\d+).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("");

// Following are all true, showing string starts with "--> NNN":
m.reset("--> 200 abc").matches();
m.reset("--> 403 xyz").matches();
```